# I’m experiencing a difficulty with "name 'x' is not defined" in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import statsmodels.api as sm


def train(x, y):
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    model = LinearRegression().fit(x,y)
    return model
data = pd.read_csv("/home/andand/Downloads/Advertising.csv")
model = train(x,y)

x_new = 23.0
y_new = model.predict(x_new)

print(y_new)




NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d0295eb57fc4> in <module>
     11     return model
     12 data = pd.read_csv("/home/andand/Downloads/Advertising.csv")
---> 13 model = train(x,y)
     14 x = data
     15 x_new = 23.0

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I suspect that my mistake is that I am not importing the training set correctly, please tell me how to do it correctly in this case.

Comment: Есть [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com). Здесь говорят только по-английски.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't belong to this site. Please post to https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: 2 upvotes ? really

Answer (score 1):

define x and y first.

Try

```
data = pd.read_csv("/home/andand/Downloads/Advertising.csv")
y = data[-1]
x = data[:-1]
model = train(x,y)
```

You have to know what is "x" in data and what is "y"

Comment: thanks for the answer, try

Comment: Always happy to help a fellow coder